# C# / LINQ / get all elements of sub-collection matching a condition?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an :

```
ObservableCollection<X> x_collection = new ObservableCollection();

public class X
{
    public X() 
    { 
         Items = new ObservableCollection<Y>();
         for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {

             Items.Add(new Y(i % 2 == 0));
         }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Y> Items {get; set;}
}

public class Y
{
    public Y() : this(true) {}
    public Y(bool y) { MyProperty = y; }
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

How do I create a LINQ query that will return an IEnumerable or ObservableCollection that will only get Y elements that have their MyProperty == true? I do realize it's probably a very easy question but I'm pretty confused with LINQ atm.

If possible I'd like to ask for a lambda-query - they're much easier for me to understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = Items.Where( y => y.MyProperty );

var biggerResult = x_collection.SelectMany( x => x.Items.Where( y => y.MyProperty ) );
```

Comment: Doesn't that return items from an X only? I need results from the whole x_collection?

Comment: Wow, that simple lol. I've noticed that when I'm casting trying to return the biggerResult as an ObservableCollection<Y> the query succeeds but the cast is null, any idea what might be wrong with that?

ObservableCollection<Y> biggerResult = query as ObservableCollection<Y>;

Comment: Please, don't compare to true! `y => y.MyProperty` will do just fine.

Comment: that's because biggerResult is IEnumerable<Y>, so it cannot be upcasted to a more specific type.

Comment: Good point, I used this as an example, in my case I'm using a specific enum check heh.

Comment: So basically, there's no way to return the query results as an ObservableCollection other then filling that collection manually from the IEnumerable<Y> ?

Comment: To avoid manually populating the ObservableCollection, you can do: `new ObservableCollection<Y>(results.ToList())`